# How to use media picker

Tags: umbraco, media, picker

I'm working on getting a Media Picker to work.

I have created a document type with a Media Picker in it called "vareBillede". This I have inserted in my code.

The code is placed in a template which should call the image from the document type.

```
@{
    var typedMediaPickerSingle = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IPublishedContent>("vareBillede");
    if (typedMediaPickerSingle != null)
    {
        <img src="@typedMediaPickerSingle.Url" />
    }
}
```

At the moment my image isn't showing up.

I really hope this makes sense and you got a fix for me :-)

Best regards
Lasse

Comment: Are you using v7 or v8?

Comment: You haven't really given us much to work with. Stick a breakpoint and see what the value of typedMediaPickerSingle is and work from there.